# Java creating a File, path is not recognized ( I guess )

Tags: java, file, maven, import

I have a file called WebUtil.Java in `src/test/java/com/x/utils`. I want to run this code:

```
File firefoxProfileFolder = new File("/../../resources/firefoxprofile");
```

in this file to create a folder in variable firefoxProfileFolder.

This folder ( firefoxprofile ) is in `src/test/resources/firefoxprofile`. What I am doing is:

```
File firefoxProfileFolder = new File("../../../resources/firefoxprofile");
```

But it does not work? What am I doing wrong? 
The error I am getting is:

```
org.openqa.selenium.firefox.UnableToCreateProfileException: Given model profile directory does not exist: ../../../resources/firefoxprofile
Build info: version: '2.25.0', revision: '17482', time: '2012-07-18 22:18:01'
System info: os.name: 'Mac OS X', os.arch: 'x86_64', os.version: '10.7.3', java.version: '1.6.0_35'
Driver info: driver.version: unknown
```

Comment: looks like the path is wrong. Relative paths are always in reference to your current working directory. Try using an absolute path.

Comment: Code will go to the server so I really do not know the absolute path. I must use relative. But what is wrong here?

Comment: The path is wrong. For testing, use an absolute path until it works, then figure out a good way to make this configurable for your server. "Current working directory" is always tricky for non-console applications. Also, if possible (not here probably) avoid Files, load resources from your jar file.

Comment: Are you using Maven to build your project?

Comment: If you don't know the absolute path, or it's not always the same, don't hard code it. Read it from a config file. Either way, the only sure way is to use the absolute path.

Comment: @DuncanJones Yes, Maven. I am new to Mac. How can I use the absolute path in Mac?

Comment: There is a file called Browser.java in the same folder. When I try: File firefoxProfileFolder = new File("Browser.java"); This does not even work. What can be the reason?

Comment: "How can I use the absolute path in Mac?"  Same way as windows/linux, don't put a leading / at the beginning, e.g. new File("../../resources/firefoxprofile");  The leading / means the root

Comment: I solved it with absolute path but I still do not understand why relative path does not work!

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Maven, you should be able to use code like this to resolve an absolute path name for a test resource:

```
URL url = getClass().getResource("/firefoxprofile");

if (url == null) {
  // ... not found
} else {
  File firefoxProfileFolder = new File(url.getPath());
  // ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're running this as part of a test (assuming you are, as the class is in the test folder), the surefire plugin will set the base directory of the Maven project as a system property.

```
String basedir = System.getProperty("basedir");
```

The basedir variable will have the directory of the project.  So then your original code could be written like

```
File firefoxProfileFolder = new File(basedir + "/src/test/resources/firefoxprofile");
```